# why set counter is not working?

Tags: numbering, setcounter

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}



\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{ relsize, stackengine}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}


\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}
\newtheorem{prob}{\emph{Problem}}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  %\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
   % matha7 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12 }{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nvartrianglelefteq}{\mathrel}{matha}{"9E}
 

\begin{document}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
   
    \newgeometry{top=1.5in,hmargin=1in, bottom = 1.1 in} 
    
    %\pagenumbering{gobble}

\Large
 \begin{center}
 Assignment 5 \\



\hspace{10pt}


\large
Jack,  \\


Nov. 10, 2021.
\end{center}

\textbf{\emph{Section 9.2}}

\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\begin{prob}[phantom=\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{19}]{}{}

$\quad$

\emph{ \lipsum[1]} 
\end{prob}
\end{document}
```

But I do not know why this line is giving me error in my code

```
\begin{prob}[phantom=\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{19}]{}{}
```

? could anyone help me correct this line? I want to each time give my problem its number (including the chapter number and the section number, like for example 4.5.36).

**EDIT:**

The error I got is:

```
  "argument> c@\tcbcounter 
                         
l.106 ...ob}[phantom=\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{19}]
                                                  {}{}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have"
```

Comment: I think I said what I want it to do, did not you read the lines at the end?@DavidCarlisle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , this is the error I got "argument> c@\tcbcounter 
                         
l.106 ...ob}[phantom=\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{19}]
                                                  {}{}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have ...."

Comment: "I want to each time give my problem its number" isn't clear to me.  Are you saying that you want your problems to be automatically numbered?  There are far easier ways to do that.

Comment: So can you please tell me how exactly the line of definition should look like?@DavidCarlisle

Comment: @Teepeemm yeah but I want them to be numbered with the numbers I put for them, like if the problem is #26 in the book, I want to give it the number 26.

Comment: Have you seen before a problem numbered as follows: "Problem 2.3.4" ?that is exactly what I want to do. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Your problems are numbered with a prob counter so as far as I can tell you just want `\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{prob}{19}
  \begin{prob}
    aaa
  \end{prob}
\end{document}`

Comment: A counter has normally no backslash in the name, you have `\setcounter{chapter}` but `\setcounter{\tcbcounter}` .

Comment: I guess that you've taken code written with `tcolorbox` in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your example can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{\tcbcounter}{19}

  \begin{prob}
    aaa
  \end{prob}
\end{document}
```

which produces the same error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> c@\tcbcounter 
                         
l.4 \setcounter{\tcbcounter}{19}
                                
?
```

because `\tcbcounter` is undefined. LaTeX counters are referenced by name by not by a command sequence, you intended `\setcounter{tcbcounter}{19}` but that produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: No counter 'tcbcounter' defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 \setcounter{tcbcounter}{19}
                               
?
```

as that counter is not defined.

You could add

```
\newcounter{tcbcounter}
```

to the preamble which would remove the error but as you never  use the counter that is not I think what you intended.

You have defined Problems to use a counter `prob` (the first argument in

`\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}`

so I think you just want to set this counter to 19

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{prob}{19}

  \begin{prob}
    aaa
  \end{prob}
\end{document}
```

which causes the problem to be numbered 20

[image]

Comment: And if OP wants numbering to include sections, then they could use the package amsthm with `\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}[section]` (as you well know).  And definitely avoid `\textbf{\emph{Section 9.2}}`.